# r - merge is only working if I do it twice?

Tags: r, merge

Can someone please explain the following output?

```
> "naics_new_code__c"%in%names(df)
[1] TRUE
> names(states)
[1] "application_state__c" "naics_new_code__c"    "loan_id"   "wa_credit_score__c"  
> df= merge(df,states,by = "loan_id")
> "naics_new_code__c"%in%names(df)
[1] FALSE
> df= merge(df,states,by = "loan_id")
> "naics_new_code__c"%in%names(df)
[1] TRUE
```

So, as you can see, on the first merge, the field "naics_new_code__c" does not become attached to my df. However, on the second merge, which is completely redundant, it does. Why would this be happening?

NOTE: this is a theoretical question about r. Adding a reproducible example would not only be superfluous in this case, but would make the answer less general and efficient for someone else with a similar problem to look up and answer for themselves.

Best,

Paul

Comment: what does `names(df)` say, initially?

Comment: it gives the names of columns in df

Comment: @Paul, did u try using '<-' instead of '=' ?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Shivam - I think we're all aware of what `names()` does. Knowing the *result* of `names(df)` in the current context would be helpful though. Changing `<-` to `=` for assignment in this case will almost certainly change nothing too.

Comment: It turns out hat "naics_new_code__c" was already in names(df), as thelatemail and Alex suggested. So on the first merge it created naics_new_code__c.x and naics_new_code__c.y, so that on the second merge it works correctly. I have added the result of "naics_new_code__c"%in%names(df) at first to my example. I am not adding a reproducible example both because it involves proprietarry information and because I firmly believe it is unneccesary in this case to solve the problem, as Alex and thelatemail have proven. I know you need standards, but come on, not all questions are the same.

Comment: A reproducible example **using your proprietary data** is certainly **not necessary**. But demonstrating the problem by providing a reproducible example of built-in or simulated data is expected of a good question, and would probably convert some of your down-votes to up-votes.

Comment: The first step of attempting to answer this question is to try to replicate the problem, which takes a little bit of work. This can be done efficiently if the asker provides reproducible code; doing so encourages high quality answers by showing that the asker is willing to put in a little work themself and making things easier for potential answerers. Conversely, a question that *doesn't* provide a reproducible example makes it seem like the asker doesn't care much, can't be bothered to demonstrate the problem, and expects potential answerers to do all the legwork.

Comment: Lastly, a reproducible example isolating the problem is a great first step when debugging. Based on your comments and edits, creating a reproducible example from the start and reading the documentation would make the question unnecessary.

Comment: @ gregor, While I think your first point can depend on circumstance and sometimes the "reproduction of the problem" can be left in the abstract, I do see the validity of your second point -- if I had made a reproducible example I likely would have answered my own question. But since not everyone does this legwork every time they run into a bug but instead go to stack overflow, doesn't the question still have some value to the community? and given that, shouldn't I pose the question in the simplest, most general way that is still clear?

Comment: sorry I ran out of time. Just wanted to add: I asked a concise question, and got a concise answer. Isn't that ok sometimes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82226/discussion-between-gregor-and-paul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `merge`:

> If the columns in the data frames not used in merging have any common
>   names, these have suffixes (".x" and ".y" by default) appended to try
>   to make the names of the result unique. If this is not possible, an
>   error is thrown.

Based on your `names` results before and after, this seems to be the case.